# How to access each row of dataframe in sparkR

Tags: sparkr

I m running R on spark using sparkR . I have created a data frame of csv file.Now I need to access each row as well data in that row.Is there any method to do that??

Comment: Please detail "access". Code speaks.

Comment: This is my code
people <- read.csv("/home/arpita/Desktop/test.csv")
peopleDf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext,people)
 
I want to access each row of data frame peopleDf

Answer (score -1):

In SparkR it is not possible to access data in that row. The possible way would be, is to covert the `sparkR data frame` to `R data frame` by using,

```
>R_people <- collect(people)

head(R_people)
##  age    name
##1  NA Michael
##2  30    Andy
##3  19  Justin

> R_people$age[3]
#19

#By using this you can filter rows in sparkR data frame `people`
> showDF(filter(people, people$age == R_people$age[3]))
##  age    name
#1  19  Justin
```

Comment: instead of down voting you can comment on things that you feel not correct.. thx